# Set unicorn timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I use `rails 3.0.11`, `ruby 1.9.3-p0`, `nginx 1.0.4` and `unicorn 3.6.2` for my project. And I have got a problem.
I have to do long-term operation on my server. It's about 150 seconds. And it's okay in this case.

I've set up my nginx config in `location`

```
proxy_read_timeout 240;
proxy_send_timeout 240;
```

And set up my `unicorn.rb` file with command

```
timeout 240
```

But I always get `502 bad gateway` error.
I think, problem with unicorn. I get this unicorn logs

```
E, [2012-05-21T11:52:21.052382 #30423] ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:30871 timeout (104.052329915s > 60s), killing
E, [2012-05-21T11:52:21.080378 #30423] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 30871 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=1
I, [2012-05-21T11:52:21.105045 #30423]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2012-05-21T11:52:21.111148 #894]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=894   
I, [2012-05-21T11:52:21.111659 #894]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
```

Can you help me? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this unicorn file is being loaded? How are you loading it?

Comment: I use [capistrano-deploy](https://github.com/lest/capistrano-deploy) gem to reload unicorn. It's interesting that `unicorn.rb` is in unix home folder, but rails app is in `web-app` folder. I never met a similar before.

Comment: I have never used this gem, but if you're doing this **after 'deploy:restart', 'unicorn:reload'** you need to restart unicorn, not only reload it. **sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn restart** and the timeout will be set. Reload and restart are two different things in unicorn.

Comment: Yeah. I solved the problem `unicorn.rb` from home is a copy of working file from `/etc/unicorn`. OMG. And it have been working after **restart**. Thank you. You helped me. But solution was funny

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: You gave the credit, that's all good by me :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> I have never used this gem, but if you're doing this **after
>   'deploy:restart', 'unicorn:reload'** you need to restart unicorn, not
>   only reload it. **sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn restart** and the timeout will
>   be set. Reload and restart are two different things in unicorn.

~ answer per [Maurício Linhares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293686/mauricio-linhares)

Answer (score 1):

After chaning timeout in config/unicron/production.rb

I had to run

```
cap deploy
```

and then stop & start unicron master process to pick up new config with:

```
cap unicorn:stop
cap unicorn:start
```